# Remove duplicates within a time range in vba (e.g. duplicates within a week)

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, date-range

I am working on a study where a study participant counts as a duplicate if they participate again within two weeks but they *aren't* a duplicate if they participate again after the 2 week cool down period. I need a way of checking/removing duplicate participants within 2 weeks but keeping them if they are a duplicate outside 2 weeks.

The data looks something like this:

```
Test    Participant ID   Date
1       550              01/01/2018
2       550              02/01/2018
3       677              05/01/2018
4       550              15/02/2018
```

Normally I would use *Range.RemoveDuplicates* to just remove duplicates. This would remove tests 2 and 4.

```
Sub removeduplicate()
Range("A1:C5").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Is there any way to modify or add to this so that I remove the duplicate in Row 2 but *not* the duplicate in Row 4 (since it is after more than 2 weeks)? I have thousands of rows.

Thank you so much

Comment: you could add a column with a formula that determines whether this record is should be considered a duplicate, perhaps returning `TRUE`/`FALSE`, and then use `RemoveDuplicates` based on that column.  Without example data, expected output, or sample code, it's tough to give you anything more specific than that.  (See "[ask]" as well as the [help/on-topic], plus great tips [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).)

Comment: Thank you ashleedawg, I have added some example data and the code I have been using to remove general duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove duplicates

```
Sub Duplicates()

Dim i As Long
 i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 x = Cells(2, 2).Value
 For j = 3 To i
If Cells(j, 2).Value = "" Then
Cells(j, 2).Value = x
Else
x = Cells(j, 2).Value    
End If
Next j
End Sub
```